# PDO Object and Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, oop, pdo

I have followed PHP Academy's OOP Tutorial over [here](https://phpacademy.org/videos/oop-loginregister-system)

The DB class has been made in a way to fetch database results as an Object

```
public function query($sql, $params=array()){
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
        $x=1;
        if(count($params)){
            foreach ($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()){
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        }else{
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

This is important cause the user login is done like this

```
public function login($username = null, $password = null){

    $user = $this->find($username);

    if($user){
        if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)){
            Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now when i want to implement foreach to get results row-wise, they are asking for an Array

```
$result = $product->getData($_GET['id']);
if(!empty($result)){
  foreach ($result as $row) {echo $row['id'];}}
```

getData Function

```
public function getData($_id){
    return $this->_db->get('products', array('id', '=', $_id))->results();

}
```

results function is in DB class

```
public function results(){
    return $this->_results;
}
```

When I change Fetch All to get Both OBJ and ARRAY, User cant log in.

What should i do? Which function to change?

Sorry for Bad English

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what does the getData function does?

Comment: you can cast your returned `object` to `array` like this `$array=(array)$object;`

Comment: That gives an error. When i printed it, it showed that the object was now in an Array

Comment: Solved! Using foreach loop on the main array and echoing as an object solved the problem